# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' name' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have some code producing the following error. How can I fix it?

```
 "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `authors` where ` name` = Azzario Razy Junaidi and `id` <> 4)"
```

---

```
AuthorsController.php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required|unique:authors, name,'.$id]);
    $author = Author::find($id);
    $author->update($request->only('name'));
    Session::flash("flash_notification", [
      "level" => "success",
      "message" => "Berhasil menyimpan $author->name"
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('authors.edit');
}
```

Comment: Which framwork are u using..??

Comment: Laravel Framework

Comment: There should be quotes around the name as>  name = 'Azzario Razy Junaidi' and id <> 4

Comment: Pay closer attention to the error. `Unknown column ' name'`.  Why do you think this says `' name'` instead of `'name'`? This is a typo, possibly here: `'required|unique:authors, name,'` but possibly elsewhere, not shown. The database is complaining that there is no column called `[space]name`.  There should not be a space before name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like your database is missing the name column on the authors table.

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 **Unknown column ' name'** in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate **from authors** where name = Azzario Razy Junaidi and id <> 4)

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove space from ( name) in your AuthorsController.php here:

```
'name' => 'required|unique:authors, name,'
```

And type this:

```
'name' => 'required|unique:authors,name,'
```

and it will work